# how to display the contents of observables from flatMap operator

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, rx-java2, rx-android

I am trying to understand how .fromCallable works, so i created the below simple example. as shown below i converted an array of integers into observables, then 
i wanted to display the contents of the flatMap. therefore, i used .map to iterate through the all the items in the array, but the observer returns

```
MainActivitygetFromCallableObserver: onNext->o: [I@18fb0dbb
```

I expected the onNext() to be called as much as the number of items in the array, and for each call to onNext(), i expected to ses each item in the array.

please let me know how to convert the array of integers to obervables and then apply the .map operator so that the onNext in the observer displays each item
separately.

**code**:

```
private void executeRxFromCallable() {
    final int[] delayValue = {-1};
    int[] nums = new int[7];
    Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<int[]>() {
        @Override
        public int[] call() throws Exception {
            while(++delayValue[0] < 7) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                Log.i(TAG, "delayValue[0]: " + delayValue[0]);
                nums[delayValue[0]] = delayValue[0] * 10;
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "total delay: " + delayValue[0]);
            Log.i(TAG, "nums.length: " + nums.length);
            return nums;
        }
    })
            .flatMap(new Function<int[], ObservableSource<?>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource<?> apply(@NonNull int[] ints) throws Exception {
                    return Observable.fromArray(ints);
                }
            })
            .map(new Function<Object, Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object apply(@NonNull Object o) throws Exception {
                    return o;
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe( this.getFromCallableObserver());

}

private Observer<? super Object> getFromCallableObserver() {
    return new Observer<Object>() {
        public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
            Log.i(TAG + "getFromCallableObserver", "onSubscribe->d: " + d);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(@NonNull Object o) {
            Log.i(TAG + "getFromCallableObserver", "onNext->o: " + String.valueOf(o));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
            Log.i(TAG + "getFromCallableObserver", "onError->e: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Log.i(TAG + "getFromCallableObserver", "onComplete");
        }
    };
}
```

**results**:

```
MainActivitygetFromCallableObserver: onNext->o: [I@18fb0dbb
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to convert a list of values into separate events using `flatMap` you could do it with a help of `Observable.fromIterable(...)` as follows:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class RxTest {
    @Test
    public void testFromCallableUsage() throws Exception {
        Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                list.add(i + 1);
                //do your sleep here
            }
            return list;
        })
            .flatMap(array -> {
                return Observable.fromIterable(array);
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(result -> System.out.println("Value : " + result),
              throwable -> System.out.println(throwable.getMessage()));

        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

**Output**

> Value : 1
>
> Value : 2
>
> Value : 3
>
> Value : 4
>
> Value : 5
>
> Value : 6
>
> Value : 7

Actually, in order to send 7 events with a period of 1000 ms between them you could use `intervalRange` as well. Then, in your `map` you could do whatever calculations/requests you need and then send them further via `Observable.just(...)`:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class RxJavaMergeTest {
    @Test
    public void testFromCallableUsage() {
        Observable.intervalRange(0, 7, 0, 1000,  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .concatMap(element -> {
                //do whatever modifications you need with your value and then send it
                return Observable.just(element);
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(result -> System.out.println("Value : " + result),
              throwable -> System.out.println(throwable.getMessage()));

        // wait until all the tasks complete
        Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case the problem is Observable.fromArray(ints); return in your map function an array not each item of ints. If you just want to try foomCallable work with a simple int not an array, it will be easier ton understand.

But I'm not sure what you trying to see with your example.

It might be something like this ?

```
private void executeRxFromCallable() {
        final int value = 42;
        Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call() throws Exception {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                return value;
            }
        })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe( this.getFromCallableObserver());

    }

    private Observer<Integer> getFromCallableObserver() {
        return new Observer<Integer>() {
            public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                Log.i(TAG + "getFromCallableObserver", "onSubscribe->d: " + d);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(@NonNull Integer o) {
                Log.i(TAG + "getFromCallableObserver", "onNext->o: " + String.valueOf(o));
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                Log.i(TAG + "getFromCallableObserver", "onError->e: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Log.i(TAG + "getFromCallableObserver", "onComplete");
            }
        };
    }
```